# Last date SQL Server query required

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

**Scenario:**

I am writing a cash management system and want to put some date columns for getting date info / history. Actually there are two columns for date in same table at this moment.

1. Voucher Date from Chart of Account Table
2. Cheque Date from Chart of Account Table

There are some values already in a table and I don’t want to delete these.

My question / scenario is that I want to get a date which is 1 day previous than the given date.

Actually creating a function so want to write a query. e.g. today is 21st September but I want to write a function that if any body mention today so it mean yesterday so it can be all details till yesterday closing. No today work mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get a date which is 1 day previous than the given date

If you only want to go back one day from a date you have, you can use [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).  For example:

```
DECLARE @today DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
-- Go back one day from the input date
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, @today)
```

But it sounds like you might actually want to grab all transactions that occur yesterday or earlier.  In that case, you could simply check for all transactions that are less than today.

```
DECLARE @today DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
SELECT ChequeDate
FROM Accounts
WHERE ChequeDate < @today
```

Or if you want just yesterday's transactions, you can combine the two approaches to create a date range that encompasses all of yesterday.  Note that you can't use `BETWEEN` in this case since you probably don't want the end of the range to be inclusive.

```
DECLARE @today DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
SELECT ChequeDate
FROM Accounts
WHERE ChequeDate >=  DATEADD(dd, 1, @today)
  AND ChequeDate < @today
```

Lastly, a point of advice: You are typically going to be get the best help on this site if you post a specific query (or even better, an entire script) that describes your question more precisely and shows what you have tried so far.  It was difficult for me to tell exactly what you were asking, and a script can help avoid misunderstanding.